# Scala append Seq in with a string in a List Map or Foreach

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm looking to append a `val adminEmailSeq = Seq.empty[String]` from a List of object attribute.

My `List[User]` called 'admins' and I'm trying to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
admins.foreach(
    admin => {
        adminEmailSeq :+ admin.email
    }
)
```

Although `admin.email` contains the right information, `adminEmailSeq.isEmpty` is always true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the description I assume that you need `Emails` from `Admins`

```
val adminEmailSeq = admins.map(_.email)
```

Answer (score 3):

The append ':+' actually doesn't append it to the leading Seq. It's making a copy.
Regarding to your solution you would need to do this.

```
admins.foreach(
    admin => {
        adminEmailSeq = adminEmailSeq :+ admin.email
    }
)
```

But I think the right solution would be using map.

Just forgot: I'm a fan of immutables and values instead of variables. It mayhelp to understand the code much easier. Therefore I wouldn't use that variable reassigning (therefore I suggested map, as some solutions here may show you).